# Docker for mac hostname insteat of IP

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, hosts

I am using the latest version of docker for mac (Version 17.05.0-ce-rc1-mac8).

When I start a new container, it opens a port which is great and works well. I would like to alias the ip and port in my hosts file (localhost:35678 -> project.local). Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Ok I set up Traefik to react as a reverse proxy, which seems to work 'ok'

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to alias the ip and port in my hosts file (localhost:35678 -> project.local)

No, that's not possible. The port is not part of the hostname.

You can use reverse proxy server, here is a nginx configuration example(**not tested**):

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  project.local;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:35678;
  }
}
```